# How to set ansible playbook to run with kornshell

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Writing ansible-playbook, to start a kornshell script.

How to set ansible to run kornshell in specific server?

```
---
- name: Start server manager agent
  hosts: 192.168.1.85
  become: yes
  become_user: jde920
  tasks:

  - name: Set ksh
    shell: ksh (not sure how to set here)

  - name: start Agent
    async: 10
    poll: 0
    shell: "./startAgent"
    args:
      chdir: "/u01/jde_home/SCFHA/bin/"

  - name: Wait for 5 seconds
    wait_for:
      timeout: 5

  - name: Start Service
    async: 10
    poll: 0
    #ansible_shell_executable: ksh
    shell: "./RunOneWorld.sh"
    args:
      chdir: "/u01/jdedwards/e920/system/bin32/"

  - name: Validate Service is up
    tags: JDE_Enterprise
    wait_for:
      host: "localhost"
      port: 6017
      delay: 20
      timeout: 60
      state: started
      msg: "JDE Enterprise Service is not Running"
```

I managed to find the file that set the environment $SYSTEM, following is the code. Script file name is call enterpriseone.sh

```
# Following has to be replaced in this file:
#
# ORACLE_HOME (if Oracle is installed)
# DB2DIR (if DB2 is installed)
# DB2INSTANCE name of user owning DB2 instance
# File Updated Tue Mar 05 16:37:23 MYT 2019 - TR 9.2.3
OS_NAME=`uname -s`

EVRHOME=/u01/jdedwards/e920
export EVRHOME

DB2INSTANCE=
export DB2INSTANCE

DB2DIR=
export DB2DIR

DB2BASEDIR=
export DB2BASEDIR

ORCL_USER_ACCT=
export ORCL_USER_ACCT

ORACLE_HOME=/u01/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1
export ORACLE_HOME

ORACLE_SID=e1db
export ORACLE_SID

set +u
SYSTEM=$EVRHOME/system
export SYSTEM
APPDEV=$EVRHOME/appdev
export APPDEV

#
# Location of INI files
JDE_BASE=$EVRHOME/ini
export JDE_BASE

## Set the binary folder to 32 or 64 bit based on the setup configuration
if [ $OS_NAME = "HP-UX" ]; then
    BUILDTYPE=$(file $SYSTEM/lib/libjdenet.so | grep 'ELF-64')
else
    BUILDTYPE=$(file $SYSTEM/lib/libjdenet.so | grep '64-bit')
fi

if [ -n "$BUILDTYPE" ]; then
   BIN_FOLDER=bin64
else
   BIN_FOLDER=bin32
fi

PATH=$PATH:$SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER
export PATH

ICU_DATA=$SYSTEM/locale/xml/
export ICU_DATA

ACRO_RES_DIR=$SYSTEM/resource/cmap
export ACRO_RES_DIR

PSRESOURCEPATH=$SYSTEM/resource/cidfont:$ACRO_RES_DIR
export PSRESOURCEPATH

#
# Call tools service pack specific environment variable
# setup script.  This script is required for running 
# the enterprise server.  If this script does not exist
# in your $SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER directory, the E1 Tools Release
# may need to be updated to a newer version.

if [ -f ${SYSTEM}/$BIN_FOLDER/toolsenv.sh ] ; then
      . ${SYSTEM}/$BIN_FOLDER/toolsenv.sh
fi
```

Below is the actual shell script (RunOneWorld.sh) that I use ansible to call:

```
## Set the binary folder to 32 or 64 bit based on the setup configuration
OS_NAME=`uname -s`
if [ $OS_NAME = "HP-UX" ]; then
    BUILDTYPE=$(file $SYSTEM/lib/libjdenet.so | grep 'ELF-64')
else
    BUILDTYPE=$(file $SYSTEM/lib/libjdenet.so | grep '64-bit')
fi

if [ -n "$BUILDTYPE" ]; then
   BIN_FOLDER=bin64
else
   BIN_FOLDER=bin32
fi

LOGFILE=$SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER"/startstop.log"

## Set START_NEW_LOGFILE=1 if you want to rewrite the logfile at each startup
START_NEW_LOGFILE=0

CLEAR_LOGS=1

## Set MULTI_INSTANCE=1 if you are running multiple instances of OneWorld
## under the same Unix user id.
MULTI_INSTANCE=0

set +u
USER=$(whoami)

HOST=$(hostname)
OSTYPE=$(uname)

## On AIX, process id shows up in column 2, it's column 1 on others...
if [ $OSTYPE = "AIX" ]
  then
    COLUMN=2
  else
    COLUMN=1
fi

unset SILENT_MODE
if [ "$1" = "-s" ] ; then
    SILENT_MODE=1
fi

## In MULTI_INSTANCE mode, we need to be able to find the INI file to get
## certain settings.  If we can't, then exit with an error.
if [ "$MULTI_INSTANCE" = "1" ] ; then
    MFLAG="-m"
    if [ -f ./JDE.INI ] ; then
      PORT_NBR=$(grep "^serviceNameListen" ./JDE.INI | sed 's/.*=//')
    elif [ -f $JDE_BASE/JDE.INI ] ; then
      PORT_NBR=$(grep "^serviceNameListen" $JDE_BASE/JDE.INI | sed 's/.*=//')
    else
      if [ -z "$SILENT_MODE" ] ; then
          print "     This script cannot support multiple instances of"
          print "     OneWorld without access to a JDE.INI file."
          print "     You must either set the $JDE_BASE environment"
          print "     variable correctly, or turn off MULTI_INSTANCE"
          print "     mode in the RunOneWorld.sh script."
          print "       exiting..." 
      fi
      print "     This script cannot support multiple instances of" >> $LOGFILE
      print "     OneWorld without access to a JDE.INI file." >> $LOGFILE
      print "     You must either set the $JDE_BASE environment" >> $LOGFILE
      print "     variable correctly, or turn off MULTI_INSTANCE" >> $LOGFILE
      print "     mode in the RunOneWorld.sh script." >> $LOGFILE
      print "       exiting..."  >> $LOGFILE
      exit 1
    fi
fi

#---------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# FUNCTION DEFINITIONS...
#---------------------------------------------------------------------- #
function GetPIDS
{
  if [ "$MULTI_INSTANCE" = "1" ]
    then
      PIDS=$(ps -ef | grep $USER | grep $PORT_NBR | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
      PIDS="$(ps -ef | grep $USER | grep $SYSTEM | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') $PIDS"
    else
      PIDS=$(ps -u $USER | grep jdenet | awk '{print $'$COLUMN'}')
  fi
  if [ "$PIDS" = " " ] ; then
      PIDS=""
  fi
}

function CheckForProcesses
{
  GetPIDS
  if [ -n "$PIDS" ] ; then
      if [ -z "$SILENT_MODE" ] ; then
          print "     There are already OneWorld processes"
          print "     running for this user / instance..."
          print "       exiting..." 
      fi
      print "     There are already OneWorld processes" >> $LOGFILE
      print "     running for this user / instance..." >> $LOGFILE
      print "       exiting..."  >> $LOGFILE
      exit 1
  fi
}

function CheckIPC
{
  $SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER/rmics.sh $MFLAG >> $LOGFILE
  if [ ! $? = 0 ] ; then
      if [ -z "$SILENT_MODE" ] ; then
          print "     IPC resource conflict -"
          print "  You may need to change the startIPCKeyValue in your INI file,"
          print "  or your JDE_BASE environment variable may be set incorrectly."
          print "       exiting..." 
      fi
      ## (error message already written to $LOGFILE by rmics.sh)
      exit 1
  fi
}


#---------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# MAIN PROCESSING...
#---------------------------------------------------------------------- #

## First, let's make sure the log file directory is valid - otherwise, all
## of the log messages will disappear.

LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
if [ ! -d $LOGDIR ] ; then
    print " Invalid directory name for LOGFILE - "
    print "  $LOGDIR"
    print " You must correct RunOneWorld.sh and retry."
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$START_NEW_LOGFILE" = "1" ] ; then
    rm $LOGFILE
fi

if [ "$CLEAR_LOGS" = "1" ] ; then
    ## If the log directory is a link, figure out what it points to...
    if [ -L $EVRHOME/log ]; then
        REAL_LOGDIR=$(ls -l $EVRHOME/log | awk '{print $NF}')
    else
        REAL_LOGDIR=$EVRHOME/log
    fi

    rm -rf $REAL_LOGDIR.prev
    mv $REAL_LOGDIR $REAL_LOGDIR.prev
    mkdir $REAL_LOGDIR
fi

print "**********************************************************" >> $LOGFILE
if [ ! $? = 0 ] ; then
    print " Unable to write to the logfile - "
    print "  $LOGFILE"
    print " You might not have permission to write to this file or directory."
    print " Make sure file permissions are set correctly and retry."
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$SILENT_MODE" ] ; then
    print "$(date)  Starting JD Edwards OneWorld on $HOST"
fi
print "$(date)  Starting JD Edwards OneWorld on $HOST" >> $LOGFILE

CheckForProcesses

if [ ! "$1" = "-n" ] ; then
   CheckIPC
fi

print "     Starting jdenet_n..." >> $LOGFILE
cd $SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER
$SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER/jdenet_n > $SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER/jdenet_n.log 2>&1 &

sleep 2
GetPIDS
if [ -z "$PIDS" ] ; then
    if [ -z "$SILENT_MODE" ] ; then
        print "     The jdenet_n process did not start..."
        print "       Check the jdenet_n.log, or the log file associated"
        print "       with the jdenet_n process id." 
    fi
    print "     The jdenet_n process did not start..." >> $LOGFILE
    print "       Check the jdenet_n.log, or the log file associated" >> $LOGFILE
    print "       with the jdenet_n process id." >> $LOGFILE
    exit 1
fi

print "     Running cleanup to check for unfinished jobs..." >> $LOGFILE
$SYSTEM/$BIN_FOLDER/cleanup &

if [ -z "$SILENT_MODE" ] ; then
    print "\n$(date)   JD Edwards OneWorld startup complete.\n"
fi
print "\n$(date)   JD Edwards OneWorld startup complete.\n" >> $LOGFILE

exit 0
```

SO in order to start the service, I will just do command as follow:
cd $SYSTEM/bin32
./RunOneWorld.sh

Answer (score 0):

For `shell` module, use the `executable` parameter instead

```
  - name: Start Service
    async: 10
    poll: 0
    shell: "./RunOneWorld.sh"
    args:
      chdir: "/u01/jdedwards/e920/system/bin32/"
      executable: /bin/ksh
```

Comment: - name: Start JDE Enterprise Service
         async: 10
         poll: 0
         shell: "./RunOneWorld.sh"
         args:
            chdir: "/$SYSTEM/bin32/"
            executable: /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: I just took a sample task from the play you have posted in the question. Is this the actual task you want to run?

Comment: Hi Bro, sorry. Just started using this website. Not sure how to properly format my code.

Comment: If I run in actual server the output as follow:

$ /usr/bin/ksh /$SYSTEM/bin32/RunOneWorld.sh
Wed Apr 15 14:17:03 +08 2020  Starting JD Edwards OneWorld on CBD2ELENT

Wed Apr 15 14:17:05 +08 2020   JD Edwards OneWorld startup complete.

Comment: Okay, which means the values for `chdir`and `executable` has to be changed accordingly.

Comment: I notice it still uses bash. For the User jde920, it is set to default to /bin/ksh shell. And in jde920 user, it able to tell $SYSTEM is the location /u01/jdedwards/e920/system/bin32/ . When I remove async and poll in playbook, the play shows me that unable to find directory /$SYSTEM/bin32.

Comment: In which shell is the variable SYSTEM exported? If you set the executable to ksh as did in this answer, it will override the default shell. So I don't think it will use bash.

Comment: I am not able to tell where SYSTEM variable exported. Because it is configured automatically. This is Oracle JD Edwards application. We just perform installation and use the RunOneWorld.sh script to startup services.

Comment: What is the error that you get when this task is run?

Comment: fatal: [192.168.1.85]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./RunOneWorld.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.034304", "end": "2020-04-15 17:17:35.604249", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-04-15 17:17:35.569945", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": " Invalid directory name for LOGFILE - \n  /bin32\n You must correct RunOneWorld.sh and retry.", "stdout_lines": [" Invalid directory name for LOGFILE - ", "  /bin32", " You must correct RunOneWorld.sh and retry."]}

Above is the error, somehow when run playbook, it not able to determine what is inside SYSTEM.

Comment: @YellowEggBro Can you hardcode the value instead of the variable $SYSTEM and try running the task?

Comment: I have tried to add the following SYSTEM=/u01/jdedwards/e920
export SYSTEM in the RunOneWorld.sh script. But when I run the script in the actual server, it says $ ./RunOneWorld.sh
 Invalid directory name for LOGFILE -
  /u01/jdedwards/e920/bin32
 You must correct RunOneWorld.sh and retry.

Comment: In the question, you have mentioned the directory as `/u01/jdedwards/e920/system/bin32/`. Isn't that the location of your script?

Comment: You are right. Fixed. Log file location need another hard code. Which I have also added in. EVRHOME=/u01/jdedwards/e920
export EVRHOME
SYSTEM=$EVRHOME/system
export SYSTEM

Comment: {"changed": true, "cmd": "./RunOneWorld.sh", "delta": "0:00:02.135620", "end": "2020-04-17 16:34:13.535821", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start                                                ": "2020-04-17 16:34:11.400201", "stderr": "./RunOneWorld.sh[78]: [: argument expected", "stderr_lines": ["./RunOneWorld.sh[78]: [: argument expected"], "stdout": "Fri Apr 17 16:34:11 +08 2                                                020  Starting JD Edwards OneWorld on CBD2ELENT\n     The jdenet_n process did not start...\n

Now it changed to above error. I do not understand.

Comment: It says it is expecting an argument to run the script.

Comment: Still not able to figure how to make the ansible playbook work.

So as a workaround, I created ansible playbook to create a shell script in that particular server, then use ansible to run that shell script to initiate the service start.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed accordingly to the following, but the script still doesn't run.

```
---
- name: Start server manager agent
  hosts: 192.168.1.85
  become: yes
  become_user: jde920
  tasks:

  - name: start Agent
    async: 10
    poll: 0
    shell: "./startAgent"
    args:
      chdir: "/u01/jde_home/SCFHA/bin/"

  - name: Wait for 5 seconds
    wait_for:
      timeout: 5

  - name: Start JDE Enterprise Service
    async: 10
    poll: 0
    shell: "./RunOneWorld.sh"
    args:
      chdir: "/$SYSTEM/bin32/"
      executable: /usr/bin/ksh

  - name: Validate JDE Enterprise Service is up
    tags: JDE_Enterprise
    wait_for:
      host: "localhost"
      port: 6017
      delay: 20
      timeout: 60
      state: started
      msg: "JDE Enterprise Service is not Running"
```

I tried to manually verified and it runs in the actual server.

```
$ /usr/bin/ksh /$SYSTEM/bin32/RunOneWorld.sh
  Wed Apr 15 14:17:03 +08 2020  Starting JD Edwards OneWorld on CBD2ELENT

  Wed Apr 15 14:17:05 +08 2020   JD Edwards OneWorld startup complete.
```